# Set Customer group using a custom register form field

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group

I have read other questions about this issue. I did what people suggested as a solution but it's not working. Actually it seems that the code is not executed at all.

I created a module. Here are the module files:

CustomX_GroupRegister.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <CustomX_GroupRegister>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <active>true</active>
    </CustomX_GroupRegister>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/CustomX/GroupRegister/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CustomX_GroupRegister>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </CustomX_GroupRegister>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <groupregister>
                <class>CustomX_GroupRegister_Model</class>
            </groupregister>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                   <CustomX_Groupregister_Model_Observer>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>CustomX_Groupregister_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>CustomerRegister</method>
                   </CustomX_Groupregister_Model_Observer>
               </observers>
            </customer_register_success>    
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/CustomX/GroupRegister/Model/Observer.php

```
    Class CustomX_Groupregister_Model_Observer
    {
        public function CustomerRegister($observer){
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('core/app')->getRequest();
            $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

            //'customer_type' is a custom field in register form
            $customer_type = $data->getParam('customer_type');

            if($customer_type == 'wholesale'){
                $customer->setData('group_id',2);  
            }else{
                $customer->setData('group_id',3);  
            }   
            $customer->save();
        }
    }
```

I have also tried to use the **customer_save_before** event. It didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you class name is not correct  in xml and also observer `GroupRegister`

`<class>CustomX_GroupRegister_Model_Observer</class>`

and same in observer

**app/code/local/CustomX/GroupRegister/Model/Observer.php**

```
Class CustomX_GroupRegister_Model_Observer
{
```

Comment: It was a silly mistake that only a fresh look would notice. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try `customer_save_after` event instead of `customer_register_success`

Comment: I did try it. Still not working though...